# How to generate a sitemap with custom posts (not Google XML)

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm looking for a way to generate a sitemap for display on my site that includes my custom posts. I'm not looking for an xml sitemap generator for search engines -- that is sorted using Google XML Sitemaps and Get Up and Running's patch for that plugin. I'm specifically looking for something to display to users. Normally, I'd use Dagon's sitemap generator, but it does not support custom posts, and the author does not seem to be responding to queries.

Any hacks/patches/code snippets/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Smart Archives Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-archives-reloaded/) plugin [should work with custom post types](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-smart-archives-reloaded-archives-dont-display-custom-post-type) (it accepts query_posts/get_posts arguments so quite flexible).

Answer (score -1):

@amanda

Hello, 
Try the beta version of Google XML sitemaps, it works for custom post. 
im using it with WP 3.0.4 without any problem.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-google-xml-sitemaps-early-testers-wanted?replies=124

mauri.

Comment: Please read the question - it says explicitly and more than once that it's not about XML sitemap.

Comment: My bad! Sorry about that.